# React - update state in the child component when parent changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-native, asp.net-core

I have a simple application with two react components:

1. vacancies.jsx - lists vacancies
2. counter.jsx - shows the number of vacancies from vacancies.jsx

When the application loads the counter shows the correct number of vacancies, but as I start adding/deleting vacancies in vacancies.jsx the count stays the same.

**vacancies.jsx:**

```
export class Vacancy extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = { vacancies: [], loading: true, title:"" };

        fetch('/api/Vacancy/Vacancies')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ vacancies: data, loading: false });
            });
    }

    delete(id) {

        var vacancies = this.state.vacancies;

        this.setState(
            {
                vacancies: this.state.vacancies.filter((v) => {
                    return (v.id != id);
                })
            });

    }

    loadVacancies(vacancies) {
        return (
            <table className='table table-striped'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Min Salary</th>
                        <th>Max Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {vacancies.map(v =>
                        <tr key={v.id}>
                            <td>{v.title}</td>
                            <td>{v.currency} {v.minSalary}</td>
                            <td>{v.currency} {v.maxSalary}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" onClick={(id) => this.delete(v.id)}>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    render() {

        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.loadVacancies(this.state.vacancies);

        return (
            <div>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const containerElement = document.getElementById('content');
ReactDOM.render(<Vacancy />, containerElement);
```

**counter.jsx**

```
import { Vacancy } from "./vacancies";

export class Counter extends Vacancy {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Items:{this.state.vacancies.length}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('counter'));
```

**UI:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the react team, they recommend using composition instead of inheritance:

> React has a powerful composition model, and we recommend using composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components.

And

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

So based on your code, recreate your `Counter` component like this:

```
export const Counter = props => {
    return (
        <div>Items: {props.items}</div>
    );
};
```

Then just change your `Vacancies` component including your new `Counter` component there:

```
loadVacancies(vacancies) {
    return (

        <Counter items={this.state.vacancies.length} />

        <table className='table table-striped'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Min Salary</th>
                    <th>Max Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {vacancies.map(v =>
                    <tr key={v.id}>
                        <td>{v.title}</td>
                        <td>{v.currency} {v.minSalary}</td>
                        <td>{v.currency} {v.maxSalary}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick={(id) => this.delete(v.id)}>Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```